# If thrusting is the most practical way of hurting a foe, why wouldn't ancient armies use barbed weapons to inflict even more damage?

Tags: warfare, weapons, medieval

I wonder why no military from history *wouldn't* make their spears and swords barbed. If the point of thrusting is to damage vital organs and cause massive blood loss, wouldn't it make more sense to design your blades to be hooked in such a way that it can tear open an exit wound and still be able to be removed with enough ease?

Would the advantages of this outweigh the downside of your fighting ability possibly getting hampered for a second or two?

Comment: It generally wasn't necessary. Most folks in armies died from disease, including infected woulds, anyway.

Comment: If thrusting *were* the most practical way... This has been debated by many, many people throughout history!

Comment: Spears were the favored weapons for two complementary reasons: they were (relatively) cheap to make, and they were easy to train new recruits to use.  Deadly combination; you can raise a bigger, reasonably competent army with the same level of resources.

Comment: @ZeissIkon building off of that, specialized troops and tactics were designed to counter those spear units, setting off the arms/armament race. This discussion can go round and round until you now have a PhD in historical arms and armaments, cannot enjoy fantasy movies anymore, and attempt to expose the troubles with every generalization on the internet. Spears are the king of melee weapons, and therefore people had to think about using them and countering them.

Comment: Barbs are meant to prevent cutting edges from being removed from a wound, not to create more damage. Putting a barb on a spear just means your spear will get stuck and can't be pulled out to stab the next guy. 

This is why spears tend to have "spadeish" shapes. It lets them pull out the spear (and likely cause more damage in the process). 

Look up "broadheads." These are modern arrow heads designed to inflict massive damage, most often used in deer hunting. They aren't barbed, but rather razor sharp, serrated, and large. They're designed to cause massive hemorrhaging in the animal.

Comment: Barbs on a sword just means the sword is far less good at cutting since it takes a lot more force to cut with it, sure is would make a heinous wound but only a shallow one, it might kill they guy from infection but not in combat when it matters.

Comment: Just to reinforce the point that retrieving your weapon was incredibly important - Roman legionaries were actually taught how *deep* to stab into their enemies, to ensure they could get their sword back for the next one.

Comment: The Elenium has a minor character make this point clear to the (comparatively thuggish) knights, to paraphrase, "why put two feet of your sword through a man when two inches will do? and what happens when you miss, that's four feet of stabbing you've wasted and now he's stabbing you instead". @GrimmTheOpiner this question has clearly had no research effort into barbed weapons - barbs exist when you want the weapon to stay stuck, which is in opposition to wanting to use the weapon efficiently.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this seems more a question about historical weapon usage than a specific issue appearing during the worldbuilding process. There should be something related to the world you're building (E.g.: I want barbed swords in my world, what can I do to make them more viable than they did historically?)

Comment: A barbed weapon sticks fast in the other guy, meaning that you lose your weapon.  Thus barbed hand-to-hand weapons are not great in non-ritualized combat.

Comment: The Roman [pilum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilum) wasn't barbed, but it was apparently designed to _bend._ The legion would throw a couple of rounds of pila, which the enemy would easily block with their shields. The legion would then charge the enemy, who were trying to figure out how to pull the pila out of their (now useless) shields...

Comment: @SimonCrase pilum wasn't *designed* to bend. Bending was just a side-effect of a long metal shaft from soft steel, as only the tip was hardened.

Comment: @Colombo Yes, I did read the _wikipedia_ article before I linked to it, so I'm aware that there are some people who think as you do.

Answer (score 44):

War is not a turn based game, where you can take all the time you need to make your move, nor is a movie or an anime where the enemies politely attack one at a time.

Once you have hit an enemy with a blade/spear, you want to have it available again as soon as possible: having to struggle for pulling it out, as it would be the case for a barbed weapon, will make you tired much sooner and will let you exposed to attacks from other enemies. Even during World War I the soldiers quickly learned that when using a shovel as a weapon it was much better to use it to hit "flat" with it and not with its edge, because the edge would have gotten stuck in the enemy.

Additionally a barbed blade would need to be used with tip attacks and not with slashing attacks, which would make the blade much less versatile on the battlefield.

Comment: Then what about barbed bullets, hmm?  HMM?

Comment: @Willk What *about* them? I'm not familiar with barbed bullets being used in any serious capacity. If you want to cause excess tissue damage, it's easier to do that with terminal ballistics (e.g., hollowpoints). Barbed *arrows* are a thing because then pulling them out is the enemy's problem, not yours.

Comment: @cadence I am fairly confident willk was making a joke. Barbed bullets get very silly, very quickly when you think about it having to rub against the outside of a barrel. Also why I would be astonished of they are, in fact, a thing!

Comment: Ah +1 there goes my answer :d

Comment: @Willk A barbed bullet would be mostly useless. You don't want any projectile to get stuck in the enemy, as that prevents blood loss. Why do you think they tell you not to remove a knife if you get stabbed? Bullets cause more damage when they fragment, hence the creation of frangible rounds and hollow points.

Comment: @Cadence Actually a hollow point bullet is kind of a barbed bullet. As the bullet deforms inside the target it becomes "barbed".

Comment: Also, have you ever tried to sharpen a serrated bread knife? Extremely difficult even with modern tools. Imagine trying to sharpen barbs with a rock.

Comment: Also, the barbs reduce weapon durability, because they break off easily.

Comment: >War is not a turn based game...

According to Swiss tradition [Arnold von Winkelried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_von_Winkelried) hurled himself onto a group of Austrian pikes, which he grabbed and held firmly. His comrades killed the pikemen while they were trying to pull out their weapons, breaking the Austrian line and leading to an Austrian defeat...

Answer (score 25):

The point (so to speak) of a thrusting attack is to concentrate as much force as possible on as small an area as possible. Greater concentration of force means it's easier to sunder armor, break bone, and rend muscle. So it follows that you want your point to be as keen and narrow as possible (while also not being too structurally weak) so as to impact as small an area as you can.

Barbs, however, *spread out* the impact. As soon as the barbs touch the enemy, they're distributing your carefully mustered force over a much larger area and the attack becomes much less potent. No armor split, no bones broken, no muscle torn.

One of the major purposes of body armor is to distribute the force of a blow across a wide enough area to make it harmless. You don't want to *help* your opponent do so. You'll have a hard enough time overcoming their armor as it is!

Comment: I agree with this post, but I would like to mention a counter-argument, which may be useful to include. Barbed projectiles can effectively remove enemies without killing them. The projectile can get stuck in shields or armor, be difficult to remove (due to barbs), and render certain critical movements or equipment useless. It's something to ponder!

Comment: @PipperChip For projectiles, yes, that makes sense. But the asker indicated that they were looking for "swords and spears" that would "still be able to be removed with ease".

Comment: The Romans would disagree about concentrating force.  The gladius was extremely broad-bladed for a thrusting sword; it's been described as "like being disemboweled with a shovel".

Comment: @Mark the tip of the gladiius would still be narrow. Once leather-based armor is pierced, opening the gap requires far less force, so the gladius can widen without requiring additional force; I suppose gladii would be less useful against medieval metal-based armor.

Comment: Voted up for using "sunder" in a sentence.

Answer (score 20):

## Cripple versus Kill:

Certainly if you only have one opponent, then barbed weapons are fine. But if you kill your opponent with a thrust, you gain no advantage from tearing at his insides. In war, you either want to kill many opponents quickly or injure many opponents and make them ineffective soldiers.

## Melee:

The guy in front of you with a melee weapon is a hazard to you as long as he can fight. It is much better to kill or cripple him quickly so he can't kill or cripple you. You can stab him and damage a vital organ - at which point, you will need to withdraw your weapon and do the same thing to the next guy - or if armor doesn't permit, you hack and crush him to death (in which case, you don't want your weapon stuck in a wound because you need regain velocity to apply more energy to him).

Adrenaline is a funny thing, though, and your opponent will likely keep fighting until you are dead or crippled - and then collapse from slow blood loss. A Pyrrhic victory is a little too late for my tastes.

The point of impact of your weapon should be tiny for a thrusting weapon to maximize penetration of armor and depth of the wound, maximizing the likelihood of lethal organ damage (or massive tissue trauma from cutting or crushing, in the case of maces, axes, etc.).

## Missile weapons:

In a missile attack, the rules are a bit different. You are trying to get him first. Here, if he is injured, he stops being a threat to you because he is likely to retreat. So at that point, the value of maiming him permanently goes up. **You DO see barbed arrows for this reason**. Additionally, you are not typically re-shooting an arrow right away that is stuck in an enemy somewhere. Your enemy MIGHT shoot your own arrows back at you, also increasing the value of barbing the arrow (it's harder to reuse). Roman spears, for example, would bend after being thrown so they needed to be repaired to re-throw.

But even here, there is value in un-barbed arrows. If you have lots of time for your opponent to bleed to death and die in agony, barbs are great. By all means, they are perfect for sieges where attrition needs to be maximized. You might be BETTER with a wounded soldier than a dead one in a siege - he needs to be cared for and fed, but is useless. But the chief way the arrow *kills* is in a deep, penetrating attack. Barbs don't help with that, and *may* even reduce effectiveness. If you anticipate winning the battle, you are likely to want to reuse your arrows later, a task made much easier without the barbs making the arrow extraction difficult or impossible. (the tip of many an arrow has been found in the bodies and bones of dead soldiers).

- All the hunting arrows I've ever worked with were designed with a mix of tiny razor blades (to maximized cutting) with a very narrow point (to optimize penetration). Unfortunately, through most of history you could only make an arrow that did one thing or the other really well.

Answer (score 13):

The problem with a barbed weapon is that if the enemy is armored (very likely) or even just has bones (practically certain) the weapon may get stuck and be impossible to withdraw in a reasonable time (= 1-2 seconds in battle, *at most*).  A common spear head can still lodge (between ribs or in the skull, for instance), but isn't anything likely to do so as a barbed spear point.

The same is true for why heavy piercing weapons like picks weren't used much in combat: too prone to getting stuck enough to take time you won't have to retrieve.

Comment: I like this answer, because getting weapons stuck is a well documented thing, but spikes were common in "heavy" weapons. Halberds, bec-de-corbans, spiked maces, guisarmes, spiked flails... Situations exist where you do want a "heavy" spike, so they were included in many polearms! Admittedly, I would not be surprised if that was not as common as spears.

Comment: Barbs can even get caught on clothing the enemy doesn't even need to be wearing armor.

Comment: I love that this answer is inclusive of enemies without bones. The boneless never get a break, amirite??

Comment: @PipperChip, the spikes of historical weapons were generally strongly tapered, to facilitate removing them from the target.

Comment: @Tom Ivar the Boneless was one of the greatest Viking watleaders, after all.

Comment: Most weapons with a cross-head or similar (as seen on many pole arms) were made that way to limit penetration.  The classic example is the boar spear, on which the cross bar was intended to keep an already fatally wounded, but not yet willing to admit it, boar from *charging up the spear shaft* and (potentially fatally) goring the hunter.

Answer (score 8):

### Real war

Real wars tended to be 99% marching and 1% battles. Then it's just politics. A side breaks and flees, you hunt some, get prisons, and get a favorable agreements with the other state. GG.

Point is that it's not about min maxing your army. You just want to achieve a particular goal. Weapons are just tools, if anything all of war is just a tool.
Whatever works good enough and checks all the boxes wins.

### Handling

Imagine a baseball bat with razor blades sticking out everywhere. Terrifying, for sure. But how you gonna be marching kilometers daily with that thing?

A spear has just one sharp and dangerous end, I know some had two. You can easily march with it in your hand and have little danger of sneezing and getting a  dissection as a result.
You can throw a bunch of spears in a cart and still not worry too much.

A sword has a scabbard. Also swords in particular are both a side arm and a daily carry self defense, or statues symbol, weapons. Civilian life and defense would be effected by military practices. You have a rapier and a war rapier, some changes but it's practically the same. Instead of having a war rapier as a war weapon and a quarter staff as a self defense weapon, it changes too much.

But back to just the practical side of things. Being able to easily and safely handle your weapon is not a small consideration. Obviously it's a bit different but ammunition and its safe handling is an important part of all armies. Also protecting storage ammunition in stuff like tanks and so on, but that's a bit different.

Barbed wire spears, a flail with a lot of heads...etc are just too challenging to even move around with. And nobody wants to burden themselves further with creating scabbards to safely handle them not just because of the money but also just practicality. It burdens the army more, costs more, and slows down the time it takes your individual solider to be ready for combat.

### Armor & shields

This is a very broad subject. But generally speaking that type of weapon is terrifying against naked human flesh. But even with bronze swords you have not only shields but also body armor. Anything from mail to some sort of hardened leather to just padded stuff to even layering your clothes.

It's just not effective at all. Sure. If you corner a half naked or lightly clothed human and swing a barbed and sharpened metal thing. But when you are facing armored humans with shields and spears it's just not as effective.

### How combat works.

Think of a spear. A one handed spear with a thrust and cut head. Now think of the most common battlefield tactic: shield wall. Now think of what part actually has contact with the enemy?
Yes. A very small part when you thrust, or a bit more when you cut.
Now think of the formation. You have a spear and a shield, your unit is not a Hollywood movie where the 100000 combatants battle ends up being 600 having fun 1v1 fights.

Real war is not a video game. You don't just have room to jump, roll, dodge...etc. You are part of a formation and limited in space and movement. Roman legionaries for example where trained in how to draw their sword with their right hand and in a reasonable movement that did not take space.

Having 6 barbed heads for your spear has no benefit if you are not able to contact them with the enemy, we already established limited in space. You just can't run around an individual enemy and contact their body with your weapon.
You have a limited window to attack and a spear, or similar weapons, are perfect for that. Anything is useless weight and materials, really.

Comment: I like the many practical considerations here, but I feel this could be made more condensed and accessible. "If I had more time, I would write a shorter letter" applied here, I suppose!

Answer (score 8):

Good answers already. My addition is that barbed melee weapons take more training and skill to use. I train with Polynesian weapons which have multiple projections. They can catch on you or your own people if not used properly before they ever hit an enemy.

Likewise, in actual combat they can be used against you if the opponent can hook into them with their weapon and rip yours out of your hands. I have a specialised weapon designed in part for this exact purpose. Difficult to use, but feared because once it captures a weapon, they either drop it immediately or lose the use of their hand forever.

[image: Weapon of peace]

Comment: "barbed melee weapons take more training" - I would imagine also are more difficult to make as opposed to a sword or a spear

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I personally think that building a barbed spear with crude, stone-age technology would be a lot more difficult than just making a normal spearhead. Even with more advanced techniques developed in the Middle Ages, it would still be easier to construct a normal spear or sword--and keep in mind, these 'normal' weapons are deadly as well. If you receive a direct hit with a sword or spear in a vital organ, barbs won't do much: you'd be dead either way. It is only when you receive a glancing blow (say, in the arm or leg) that barbs would exacerbate injuries.

Comment: Stone points with barbs are rather common -- look at Native American arrow points made into the 19th century.  Larger points weren't often barbed because the barbs were fragile and making them was extra effort, but they were very practical to make when there was a reason to (for instance, to give an arrow a larger wound channel).

Answer (score 1):

### Humans are Pretty Easy to Kill

Inflicting "more damage" was generally not required with melee weapons. A three inch deep stab wound in the gut is fatal without rapid, modern medical attention.

So a Roman gladius would be plenty deadly with a very shallow stab. Doing "more damage" might have the advantage of killing the enemy faster (because they bleed out more quickly), but that's probably not necessary. A mortal wound is likely to put the enemy in shock, and blood loss makes it hard to keep fighting, even if actual death takes many minutes.

A barbed weapon is much harder to build/maintain, harder to train, more likely to get stuck in the enemy, etc. and thus the simpler stabbing weapon - which is "good enough" - has historically been the accepted answer.